# Object assignment in place of parameter in the constructor

Tags: javascript, function, class, constructor, arguments

In the class below, for the constructor the parameter used is

> { cabinet = 'spruce', distortion = '1', volume = '0' } = {}

```
class GuitarAmp {
  constructor ({ cabinet = 'spruce', distortion = '1', volume = '0' } = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, {
      cabinet, distortion, volume
    });
  }
}
```

Generally argument is passed to a constructor, I didn't understand why an assignment is present here.

Taken the code from [here](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-s-the-difference-between-class-prototypal-inheritance-e4cd0a7562e9)

Answer (score 0):

It's not an assignment. This is two stuff chained together:

- [Default parameter value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

  ```
  constructor(options = {}) {
  ```
- [Destructuring assignment with default values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2)

  ```
  let {cabinet = 'spruce', distortion = '1', volume = '0'} = options
  ```

Remove `options` then you get the code in your question.